# Difference of memory counts and which one counts for compute units

Tags: apify

I developed an actor and ran it with an memory limit of 1024MB. When I ran it a critical memory overload warning appeared in the log, with an actual memory value (>900MB) close to the limit. So far so good.
When I checked the 'Max' memory info-tab of the run and it showed a much less value (534,4MB), thich didn't fit to the above value (attachement 2).

What is the difference of both values? Which one counts for the compute units?

[critical memory overload warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vNcNU.png)

[memory value on info tab of run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z81Cs.png)

Comment: What `apify` version are you using? This has been a bug some months ago, but it should have been fixed in versions > v0.15 (latest is currently 0.16.0).

Answer (score 0):

The compute unit consumption is based on the **selected memory limit**, not the real time memory consumption.

Thus, if you selected a memory **limit of 1024MB**, the actor will consume compute units at a rate of **1CU per hour**, irrespective of whether it actually consumed 100MB or 900MB of memory.

This makes sense because the memory is allocated to the run and no other user can use it at this time.